# VS2017 update to 26403 causes Service Fabric issues

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Yesterday I updated VS2017 with the newly available update (now at 26403.0 release). Since doing this I have a few Service Fabric problems:

1. First, it reverted my Service Fabric core/SDK installations from 5.5.216/2.5.216 back to 5.4.145.9494/2.4.145.9494. I noticed this when I opened my solution and was given this warning:

[image: Requires SDK 2.5 or higher warning]

This was fixed by installing the latest core/SDK again with WebPI.

2. Using VS F5 build, I am able to create a cluster on the default C drive and run my application. However, I normally use this Powershell command to move it to D drive where I have more space. But this no longer works:

   ```
   & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1" -PathToClusterDataRoot d:\SfDevCluster\data -PathToClusterLogRoot d:\SfDevCluster\log -Auto -CreateOneNodeCluster
   ```

Since the update, I now get this error:

```
    Cluster manifest validation failed with exception System.ArgumentException: Error occurs in section Diagnostics, parameter  System.Fabric.Management.ServiceModel.SettingsOverridesTypeSectionParameter. The error message is System.ArgumentException: Section Diagnostics parameter EnableCircularTraceSession found in cluster manifest but not Configurations.csv in system.fabric.management.dll.
   at System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.WindowsFabricSettings.MergeConfigurationsAndClusterManifest(Dictionary`2 configurations, Dictionary`2 clusterManifest, Boolean skipValidation)
   at System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.WindowsFabricSettings.MergeConfigurationsAndClusterManifest(Dictionary`2 configurations, Dictionary`2 clusterManifest, Boolean skipValidation)
   at System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.WindowsFabricSettings..ctor(ClusterManifestType manifest, Boolean skipValidation)
   at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore() Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest : Cluster manifest validation failed with exception System.ArgumentException: Error occurs in section Diagnostics, parameter System.Fabric.Management.ServiceModel.SettingsOverridesTypeSectionParameter. The error message is System.ArgumentException: Section Diagnostics parameter EnableCircularTraceSession found in cluster manifest but not Configurations.csv in system.fabric.management.dll.
   at System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.WindowsFabricSettings.MergeConfigurationsAndClusterManifest(Dictionary`2 configurations, Dictionary`2 clusterManifest, Boolean skipValidation)
   at System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.WindowsFabricSettings.MergeConfigurationsAndClusterManifest(Dictionary`2 configurations, Dictionary`2 clusterManifest, Boolean skipValidation)
   at System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.WindowsFabricSettings..ctor(ClusterManifestType manifest, Boolean skipValidation)
   at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.ValidateAndEnsureDefaultImageStore()
    At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:406 char:5
    +     Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest -ClusterManifestPath "$manifest ...
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricClusterManifest], ClusterManifestValidationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterManifestErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestClusterManifest
```

Also since the update, I am also getting a **runtime** reference error when I invoke a method from an ASP.NET core stateless service calling a SF stateful service. This only happens from my ASP.NET core project, another Web Api 2 project I have in the same solution is able to call the same stateful service method no problem. I'm not sure how this is related to the VS update, but it wasn't occurring pre-latest-update. All projects in my solution are loaded up with Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.2 (latest), so I'm not sure where 10.0.0 is being referred to. I'll investigate this part some more - just thought it may be helpful if others have similar issues since updating VS.

```
    {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have this setting in your local cluster manifest under Diagnostics? EnableCircularTraceSession

Comment: Yes - it is set to true.

Comment: I had the same error after updating visual studio. The only solution I found to get the azure tools 2.5 installed was a complete uninstall / install of vs 2017. I had to download the latest vs 2017 installer and download all the 6.4 GB needed again. I tried many things but complete reinstall was the only things that worked. I dont see any other options to get the azure sdk updated

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TonyFabian - a big pain but I'll give it a try.

Comment: So, reinstalling with WebPI fixed the core/SDK version downgrade issue. The cluster deployment on D drive just started working - no idea why as I haven't changed anything. And the Newtonsoft.Json issue seems to be related to 10.0.2 - as when I rolled back to 10.0.1 it works fine.

Comment: VS2017 installer only upgrades SF tooling but not the SF SDK itself which you need to upgrade using WebPI. Those are two separate components now which is a change compared to VS2015 workflow.